# What design pattern should I choose for different classes with common ancestor and common descendants?

Tags: delphi, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

I'm refactoring some of my code at the moment. I got two - mostly redundant - units, one for each product. Both contain a baseclass that inherits few subclasses. These inherit more subclasses, as well.

Now I want to merge both units, so that redundant code won't be redundant anymore and differing parts are implemented separately in two different units.

I first thought of some hierarchie like the following:

```
                        BaseClass
                           / \
                          /   \
                         /     \
                        /       \
                       /         \
                      /           \
                     /             \
                    /               \
                   /                 \
                  /                   \
         Product<A>BaseClass   Product<B>BaseClass
                  \                   /
                   \                 /
                    \               /
                     \             /
                      \           /
                       \         /
                        \       /
                         \     /
                          \   /
                           \ /
                            X
                           /|\
                          / | \
                         /  |  \
                        /   |   \
                       /    |    \
                      /     |     \
                     /      |      \
                    /       |       \
                   /        |        \
                  /         |         \
                 /          |          \
                /           |           \
               /            |            \
         SubClass<1>   SubClass<2>   SubClass<3>
             / \                          |
            /   \                         |
           /     \                        |
          /       \                       |
         /         \                      |
        /           \                     |
       /             \                    |
SubClass<1.1>   SubClass<1.2>       SubClass<3.1>
```

But the problem is the `X`, where inheritance joins underneath product-specific classes, as such inheritance isn't possible in the Delphi language.

So, I think there has to be a design pattern, that is useful to implement such model with common parent class and common descendant classes?

---

**EDIT:** I made an UML class diagram to clarify the current situation.
[image: UML diagram of current situation]

Comment: You can build it with interfaces.

Comment: @TLama But how do I implement the code then? What should be the interfaces? All classes (besides those product-classes) do already exist.

Comment: Sorry, I meant design, not build.

Comment: It's not clear to me that there is a design pattern for this. The language does not support such a design.

Comment: Like TLama said, use interfaces and delegate common functionality to classes on their own. *Use* those classes in your BaseClass and descendants. [Favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: What is X? The 'diamond' shape of class design often leads to confusion. Why not have `Product<A>BaseClass ` and `Product<A>BaseClass ` together (one class) or if they should be separate, have separate subclasses? As far as a pattern, have you considered [delegation via interfaces](http://delphi.org/2014/02/hidden-features-in-the-delphi-object-pascal-language/) as a pattern, instead of normal polymorphism? That allows you to have a set of classes with the same interfaces, where you don't have to rewrite the implementation because you delegate to another (shared) class.

Comment: It seems to me that "x" needs to hold both references to class A and B: in this case the *composition* may be the way to go. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html

Comment: Your reference to 'product' leads me to think that you're using OOP for data modeling.  I prefer to use OOP for system design.

Comment: Do those diagrams represent the layout of two different units? Or do they represent two different evolvements of the same BaseClass in your project/library?

Comment: @NGLN Two different units used by different projects. Second one is the result of copy-pasting the first one, that happened some years ago. Since then both units evolved a bit, so that they slightly differ, but most of the code is still identical.

Comment: Then what's your question here? Why can't you just merge both units into one? Why would you want another hierarchy? If both units have a base, descendants and sub-descendants, then how could you merge a sub-descendant from the one with a sub-descendant from the other? Aren't you making this a bit too complicated? Or else, please give an example of the specific problem, because I don't see it.

Comment: This is the problem with obsessing over inheritence as your mechanism to reuse code and remove duplication. It ignores the most natural way to reuse code, i.e.: Simply ***use other objects***. You almost certainly have a problem in that your current objects are doing "too much". Extract common functionality into separate classes. (NOTE: **interface**s as suggested by others, are not necessary, but they might be useful in some situations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your actual classes nor knowing what you are trying to achieve it is difficult to give an answer, because there are many considerations.

True multiple inheritance like that of C++ is not possible. You can do something similar with interfaces but that would not seem to be appropriate here because you have not indicated that any classes derive solely from A or B, so if you implemented them you would have to move all actual function definitions to X anyway.

But what is X? Consider it logically. If A is, say, a fruit and B is Round and X is an Orange, then as NGLN says you need to merge A and B into X, (or BaseClass) and throw A and B away.

On the other hand if A were, say Petrol Tank, B headlight and X car, then X would contain two class members A and B, and subclasses would reference those members.

On the third hand if there actually are classes derived solely from A and solely from B then you may choose to use interfaces and live with the fact that some implementations may have to be duplicated in descendants of A (and separately in B) and in X, or, perhaps equivalently, derive X from baseclass and duplicate the functions of B and C in X. Neither of these last two options are ideal, and you may choose to merge them anyway and derive everything from X regardless of if it were really from A or from B.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I want to merge both units, so that redundant code won't be redundant anymore and differing parts are implemented separately in two different units.

If `A` and `B` descend from `BaseClass` and each still have *something* in common (your X), then you should realize that *something* should be part of the `BaseClass`. That is your solution and it really is that simple.

If `A` and `B` delegate execution to external code (with events, callback routines, etc...) which happens to be the same code for each of them, unknowingly, then that is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to detail what [NGLN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757830/ngln) explained in his answer, since it seems to be the best one, considering the information you given.

Consider the following class model as a possible solution for you:

```
TProduct = class
  // Declarations for any product
end;

TProductA = class(TProduct)
 // Declarations for any products of kind A
end;

TProductB = class(TProduct)
  // Declarations for any products of kind B
end;

TProductA1 = class(TProduct)
  // Declarations for product A1
end;

TProductA2 = class(TProduct)
  // Declarations for product A2
end;

TProductB1 = class(TProduct)
  // Declarations for product B1
end;

// Other product declarations
```

Unless you have other complicating conditions, this seems to be what you need!